# VBA Macros not working first time after download

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macros that it doesn't work on the first time after download when I activate the macros in the office.
it gives an error on the line

```
Sheets(cListeV).Unprotect
```

After further testing when i change Unprotect with Sheets(cListeV).Select or Sheets(cListeV).Visible = True and event Sheets.count it raises the same exception
when I changed this by `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(cListeV).Unprotect` it gives an error in other line

```
For Each Na_Range In ActiveWorkbook.Names
```

and the function of workbook_open :

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim UserAnswer
    Dim Version As String
    Dim Title As String

    'Format WS
        UserAnswer = MsgBox("would u confirm validation ?" & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & " of file", vbYesNo)
        If UserAnswer = vbYes Then
            SetUpSheets
        End If

    'Set F1 key to DisplayHelp
        SetF1Key


    'Display Title and date's template in status bar
        'Read title & comments from file properties
        Version = ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Comments")
        Title = ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Title")

        'Display tile & version in status bar
        Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
        Application.StatusBar = Title & " - " & "Version : " & Version

End Sub
```

when I searched for the reason I think it's related to the focus of the excel.
when I close the file and launch the macros again the excel VBA works perfectly.
can someone point me how to correct this error.
thanks in advance.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Try changing it to ThisWorkbook.Names but we also might benefit from knowing the error or seeing more code.

Comment: for Sheets(cListeV).Unprotect it gives me Execution Error '1004' Method 'sheets' of object '_Gobal' failed

Comment: ThisWorkbook.Names worked but it doesn't give me selection of sheet it give me another error select method of worksheet class failed 1004 when i do sheet selection.

Comment: It would help to see all code in your Workbook_Open event.

Comment: @user1655410 did you manage to fix your issue ?

Comment: yes,its a security thing concerning the execution of the macro when the file is downloaded from the internet causing the stylesheet to lose their focus. So i disabled security option for files downloaded from the internet and it worked in the confidentiality parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try by adding the password of your file :

`ThisWorkbook.worksheets(cListeV).Unprotect "MyPassword"`

Edit 1

```
ThisWorkbook.worksheets(cListeV).Unprotect Password:="password"
```

Comment: i tried your code but it didn't work it gave same errors as before

Comment: @user1655410 what contains CListeV

Comment: a name of a stylesheet

Comment: @user1655410 can you edit and add the full sub where you unprotect the sheet  ?

Answer (score 0):

What is the sheet called that you're attempting to unprotect? Here's an example that works exactly like @Dorian's example above but written slightly differently.

```
Sub UnprotectSheet()

    Dim thisBook        As Workbook: Set thisBook = ThisWorkbook
    Dim sheetTwo        As Worksheet: Set sheetTwo = thisBook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    sheetTwo.Unprotect Password:="password"

End Sub
```

The part where you're defining the sheet you want to unprotect needs to reflect the name  exactly. If the name of the sheet is "cListeV" then you'd have to define it like this:

```
thisWorkbook.Worksheets("cListeV").Unprotect Password:="password"
```

Comment: the sheet doesn't contain any password though, im just trying with unprotect to disable sheet protection if enabled. No password is specified on the sheet. the vba macros works perfectly locally, but when i downloaded it from a website it gives me that errors. when i close and open the excel file no error is given. the macro works as it's supposed to after download.